# Alternative to xml files in Magento

Tags: magento

Is there any alternative to xml files in magento? why?

As per my knowledge we have to use xml files to activate and run our module but still I want to know whether is it possible or not.

-Thanx.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... What made you wonder that? The only reason that came to mind was the lack of branching syntax in magento XML files.

Comment: It was just a curiosity....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there aren't any alternatives - at least not out of the box.

Whether it it possible... Well I wouldn't advise it but since you have the source code at your mercy you could always rewrite the code that is reading XML files (e.g. Mage_Core_Model_Config::loadModules) to read configuration from somewhere else ;)